# unable to show/hide in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, show-hide

please see my fiddle
when you scroll to bottom of the page a div appears and the top panels hides. but when i the x button at bottom it doesnt close.

what i want it when i click clode button the parent div should hide and the top div should show again

this is my fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/cancerian73/VHuFQ/2/

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= ($(document).height() - $(window).height())) {
        $('.bottom-teaser').animate({
            "right": 10,
            "opacity": "1"
        }, "slow");
        $('.top-icons').hide();
    }
});

    $('#x-button').click(function () {
    $('.bottom-teaser').parent().hide();
    $('.top-icons').show();
   return false;
});
```

Comment: I think you named your 'id' wrong. Look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/VHuFQ/4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your id is mismatching it is `x_button` not `x-button`

```
$('#x_button').click(function () {
    $('.bottom-teaser').hide();
    $('.top-icons').show();
    return false;
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/x3jPz/)

Also you don't want to hide the parent of `bottom-teaser` because the parent is the `body` element, you just need to hide the `bottom-teaser` element.

```
$(function () {
    $('#x_button').click(function () {
        $('.bottom-teaser').animate({
            "opacity": "0"
        }, "slow");
        $('.top-icons').show();
        return false;
    });
})
```

Comment: hi Arun i tried here as you can see on my site but somehow it works in fiddle and not here what am i doing wrong? http://www.spheretekk.com/tumblr/ and path to my js http://www.spheretekk.com/tumblr/js/tumblr-custom.js and also when i scroll again the top icons get hidden  thank you

Comment: @San in your page the id is `x-button` not `x_button`

Comment: Hi Arun im sorry once again..i did changed the id but its still not happening what silly mistake am i committing

Comment: @San your click handler is not within an dom ready handler.. `$(function(){.....})`

Comment: you are  star... thanks a ton... but now im in other dilemma....on .scrollTop() even my top icon gets hidden when you go to top and scroll back down again

Comment: hi arun i tried this but this is not working with my js $(function(){
 if ($(".bottom-teaser").css("display", "none")) {
            $('.top-icons').show();
        } else {
            $('.top-icons').hide();
        }
    });
 });

Comment: @San try `$(function () {
    $('.top-icons').toggle($(".bottom-teaser").is(":visible"));
});`

Comment: Hi arun, no this is not working i tried on this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/cancerian73/JLH66/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42999/discussion-between-arun-p-johny-and-san)

Answer (score 2):

Typo on line 12: it's currently:

```
$('#x-button').click(function () {
```

and should be:

```
$('#x_button').click(function () {
```

WORKING: 
http://jsfiddle.net/vimes1984/VHuFQ/3/